# Are there more specific official rules on Barbarian Rage and Combat Expertise?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

[D&D 3.5 Barbarian Rage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/barbarian.htm#rage)<sup>D20SRD</sup> has a more explicit list of prohibited actions than its [Pathfinder's counterpart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Rage-Ex-).

In particular, the former prevents the use of command word, spell trigger and spell completion items as well as the Combat Expertise, metamagic feats and creation feats (amusing). The latter, only specifies the skills that can be used and prevents any activity *that requires patience or concentration*.

**1) [Pathfinder only] Is using the Combat Expertise feat an activity that requires concentration? Or is it left ad GM's fiat?**

**2) [Both systems] If Combat Expertise is locked out during a rage, are feats for whom it is a prerequisite (e.g.: Improved Disarm, Whirlwind Attack) locked out too?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have my Pathfinder books with me, so I'll just say if Pathfinder doesn't explicitly mention Combat Expertise in the Rage description, then by default it falls to GM fiat.

Since Combat Expertise is explicitly called out in the Barbarian Rage description and the other feats aren't, I would allow use of the other feats in the Combat Expertise tree while raging. Whirlwind Attack practically screams to be used while raging.

Comment: +1: That's exactly my interpretation. I just need community feedback just to give to my player a more reasoned point of view and "officialism". Thank you ^_^

Comment: You could also argue that since Barbarians cannot use Int-based skills, they could also not use feats which require a minimum Int (Ala, Combat Expertise)

Comment: Yeah, but the cascading feats are still an issue since the prerequisite feat has a minimum Int requirement. And denying Whirlwind Attack to a raging barbarian just seems wrong to me.

Comment: That's still the same issue as if you disallow the prerequisite feat, do you allow the descendants, though. Barring the Prereq regardless of reason still brings up that problem.

Answer (score 6):

The rules say that barbarians "cannot use" Combat Expertise. It does not say that they lose access to the feat, nor that they are considered not to have it. Therefore, Rage would not turn off the feats for which it is a requirement, unless those feats are explicitly included in the "things a raging barbarian cannot do" list.